# how can I redirect to a phone dial when users click on a phone number

Tags: html, css

The code im using is correct but somehow its not clickable and not working, i guess because of some css but can not find out

my website is reelgruptemizlik[dot]com and you can see the phone number right side of the logo "0 538 463 73 35"

Comment: We need to see the code to have any chance of helping you

Comment: I know but I dont know what code triggers that the tel option not work. When I investigate via chrome console, something related with the css is blocking the click function. can you please go to the site and check it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML `a` tag to redirect to the phone app. Check the below code.

```
<a href="tel:05384637335">0 538 463 73 35</a>
```